# What is the best way to store column oriented table in MongoDB for optimal query of data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a large table where the columns are user_id, user_feature_1, user_feature_2, ...., user_feature_n

So each row corresponds to a user and his or her features.

I stored this table in MongoDB by storing each column's values as an array, e.g.

```
{
   'name': 'user_feature_1',
   'values': [
   15,
   10,
   ...
   ]
}
```

I am using Meteor to pull data from MongoDB, and this way of storage facilitates fast and easy retrieval of the whole column's values for graph plotting.

However, this way of storing has a major drawback; I can't store arrays larger than 16mb.

There are a couple of possible solutions, but non of them seems good enough:

1. Store each column's values using gridFS. I am not sure if meteor supports gridFS, and it lacks support for slicing of the data, i.e., I may need to just get the top 1000 values of a column.
2. Store the table in row oriented format. E.g.

   {
       'user_id': 1,
       'user_feature_1': 10,
       'user_feature_2': 0.9,
       ....
       'user_feature_n': 42
    }

But I think this way of storing data is inefficient for querying a feature column's values

Or MongoDB is not suitable at all and sql is the way to go? But Meteor does not support sql

**Update 1:**
I found this interesting article which talks about array in mongodb is inefficient. https://www.mongosoup.de/blog-entry/Storing-Large-Lists-In-MongoDB.html

Following explanation is from http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

*Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}. The keys must be in ascending numerical order.*

This means that we can store at most 1 million values in a document, if the values and keys are of float type (16mb/128bits)

Comment: "seems good enough", "I think", ... Performance is not about feelings or opinions, it's about benchmarks and profiles. Where are yours?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a third option. A separate document for each user and feature:

```
{ u:"1", f:"user_feature_1", v:10 },
{ u:"1", f:"user_feature_2", v:11 },
{ u:"1", f:"user_feature_3", v:52 },
{ u:"2", f:"user_feature_1", v:4  },
{ u:"2", f:"user_feature_2", v:13 },
{ u:"2", f:"user_feature_3", v:12 },
```

You will have no document growth problems and you can query both "all values for user x" and "all values for feature x" without also accessing any unrelated data.

Comment: Every value will need at least two identifiers (user_id and user_feature). Won't this approach take up space? I am thinking the possibility of using both mongodb and postgres for meteor, just found out that there are libraries that support postgres for meteor

Comment: @Michael Surely it wouldn't be the most space-efficient solution. There is always a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

`16MB / 64bit float = 2,000,000 uncompressed datapoints`. What kind of graph requires a minimum of 2 million points *per column*??? Instead try:

- Saving a picture on an s3 server
- Using a map-reduce solution like hadoop (probably your best bet)
- Reducing numbers to small ints if they're currently floats
- Computing the data on the fly, on the client (preferred, if possible)
- Using a compression algo so you can save a subset & interpolate the rest

That said, a document-based DB would outperform a SQL DB in this use case because a SQL DB would do exactly as Philipp suggested. Either way, you cannot send multiple 16MB files to a client, if the client doesn't leave you for poor UX then you'll go broke for server costs :-).

Comment: Plotting graph is one of the required functions, I need to store all values for other purposes, such as statistics calculation.

Comment: Sounds like you should go with with Philipp suggested if you need perfect resolution.